# How to use FullAjaxExceptionHandler with a PrimeFaces actionListener

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, exception, omnifaces

I am confused about how OmniFaces's [`FullAjaxExceptionHandler`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) should work with a PrimeFaces `<p:commandButton>` that is supplied with an `actionListener`. With a regular `<h:commandButton>`, the error page shows up correctly, however with a `<p:commandButton>`, nothing happens and the exception is only logged to console.

My environment: PrimeFaces 4.0, GlassFish 3.1.2.2, OmniFaces 1.6.3.

View:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{errorTester.throwRuntimeException}"
                     value="PrimeFaces" />
    <h:commandButton value="JSF"
        action="#{errorTester.throwRuntimeException}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

The bean method:

```
public void throwRuntimeException() {
    throw new RuntimeException("peek-a-boo");
}
```

How do I have configure the `<p:commandButton>` to get the exception handled by `FullAjaxExceptionHandler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main mistake is that you're (ab)using an `actionListener` for business actions while that isn't intented for that. You should use the `action` for that.

```
<p:commandButton action="#{errorTester.throwRuntimeException}" 
                 value="PrimeFaces" />
```

If an exception is thrown from an `actionListener`, then all remaining `actionListener`s and the `action` will be skipped and JSF will proceed to render response.
I understand that PrimeFaces showcase is cluttered with abused `actionListener`s for business actions over all place, but you shouldn't use that as an excuse to also do that yourself.

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/)

Comment: Oh damn, sorry about the delete :) I've found the SO question about action vs actionListener, figured it out and then I was literally like 'hope BalusC hasn't started writing an answer yet' :D